# Using qRegisterMetaType on object pointer with Qt5 throws unresolved errors

Tags: c++, qt, qmetaobject

I'm currently porting my application from Qt4.8 to Qt5.6

Some code that use to compile and link now stopped linking properly.
I narrowed it down to a call to `qRegisterMetaType<MyClass*>` where MyClass* inherits from QObject.

MyClass is defined and implemented in a separate plugin. So in this context, I'm simply including "MyClass.h" in which I have a `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass*)`

It use to work perfectly with Qt4.8 but with Qt5.6 but now it fails to link:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const MyClass::staticMetaObject"
```

What has changed with Qt5? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Missing `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class (which in turn makes `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` useless, see the notes at the end of [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)).

Comment: @peppe author is talking about POD type - a pointer to class.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: a class which is a QObject subclass (but without the `Q_OBJECT` macro); such pointers are automatically registered with the metatype system, check the link I've pasted, but I suspect they *do* require the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: @peppe i know documentation well. It doesn't matter when you are trying to register metatype of a pointer. It is not possible to call Q_DEACLARE_METATYPE for QObject-based types, because they have no copy ctor.

Comment: I think that @Julien has a problem because he registered a pointer but somewhere try to use a type directly.

Comment: Q_OBJECT macro is there, however the .h file is not in the HEADER of my .pro so I guess it's not moc'ed

Comment: @peppe @DmitrySazonov I'm able to call ```qRegisterMetaType<MyClass*>``` if I declare ```Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER(MyClass*)``` which does not make sens because the documentation says:   
> This function requires that T is a fully defined type at the point where the function is called. For pointer types, it also requires that the pointed to type is fully defined. Use Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER() to be able to register pointers to forward declared types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never, the answer is indeed to use the macro mentioned in the comments above. It is more or less explained in the manual for `int qRegisterMetaType(const char *typeName)`

> This function requires that T is a fully defined type at the point where the function is called. For pointer types, it also requires that
>   the pointed to type is fully defined. Use Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER()
>   to be able to register pointers to forward declared types.